# One view, two Comboboxes with filters interferes each other filters

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I've created a FilterCombobox that inherits from Combobox.
This FilterCombobox filters the result based on the users input. 
In my view I have two of these FilterCombobox's and they reference the same ObserveableCollection.

1. I can filter in one FilterCombobox1 without filter the other, but
2. When I change focus to the next FilterCombobox2, the FilterCombobox1 is filtered according to the filter applied in FilterCombobx2 after the third'ish letter (looks like this a recurring pattern)

If I have two seperate ObserveableCollection then this issue does not invoke, so I mistake that my filter method does something to the actual ObserveableCollection.

Filter method:

```
private void SetFilterToTextInput()
        {
            Items.Filter += a =>
            {
                var propertyString = GetPropertyString(a);
                if (propertyString.ToUpper().Contains(Text.ToUpper()))
                    return true;
                return false;
            };
        }
```

This is my XAML implementation of these two FilterComboboxes:

```
<Controller:FilterComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Collection,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding Left, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
    Width="135"
/>
<TextBlock Margin="0,5,5,0" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" >-</TextBlock>
<Controller:FilterComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Collection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding Right, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
    Width="135"
/>
```

Comment: Looks like I've got a work around with this small snippet `_filteredView = new CollectionViewSource { Source = Items.SourceCollection }.View;
                this.ItemsSource = _filteredView;` Though I don't know the impact of this solution.